# How to fill DataSet with multiple tables in c# to send it to Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Guys I have 2 tables in `SQL Database` and I want bring them to my Crystal Report I watched some videos that talking about just one table.

Now I want my Data that Displayed in crystal report just I want it when I enter the Data from `Textbox` this is my codes.

```
private void butSearchByTextbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=. ; DataBase=WaterProject; Integrated Security = true");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(" SELECT Table1.data , Table2.data FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Name Like '" + textBox1.Text + "'", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Info");
        SubscriberData CryRep = new SubscriberData();
        CryRep.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["Table1"]); // I want multi tables
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CryRep;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show both table schemas and data and expected output? Also, test your query in SSMS to see if it works.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thanks for replay.
I tested it in my sql server its work with best way. Just when I search I want the result appears just when    `where Table1.Name Like '" + textBox1.Text + "'`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve my case with my self.

The code is working just I add `Table1.Id = Table2.Id` , And I make some change for `App.config` File It will became like this

```
 <startup  useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
</startup>
```